# Limitar numero de registros en tabla sqlite

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

hay alguna forma de limitar el numero de registros de una tabla, es decir, he creado una tabla para registrar un usuario y una contraseña, y quiero que solo se pueda añadir un registro a esta tabla, es decir, solo se pueda añadir un usuario y una contraseña, cuando intente añadir otro, no me deje, me salga un toast mostrando el mensaje "usuario ya registrado", me pueden ayudar? 
gracias de antemano,
creo la tabla:

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table registro(usuario text, contrasena text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if exists registro");
    db.execSQL("create table registro(usuario text, contrasena text)");
}}
```

aqui donde hago el registro:

```
public class registro extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et1,et2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
    et1 = findViewById(R.id.et_usuarioregistro);
    et2 = findViewById(R.id.et_loginregistro);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // para que aparezca el boton atras en toolbar
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // para activar boton atras action bar
            Intent a = new Intent(this, login.class);
            startActivity(a);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_forward_in, R.anim.zoom_forward_out);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
public void registrologin(View v){

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"registro.db", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        String usuario = et1.getText().toString();
        String contrasena = et2.getText().toString();
        ContentValues registro1 = new ContentValues();  //es una clase para guardar datos
        registro1.put("usuario", usuario);
        registro1.put("contrasena", contrasena);
        bd.insert("registro", null, registro1);

        bd.close();
        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Quieres que si un usuario mete el nombre de un usuario existente le salga un toast indicando que ese usuario ya existe ?, no me queda muy claro lo que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías crear una función para comprobar que el usuario existe. Por ejemplo

```
public boolean existeUsuario(String user){
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"registro.db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE usuario = '" + user + "'";
    return c.moveToFirst()?true:false;
}
```

Llamando a una función como la que tienes ahí y pasándole el usuario te debería devolver true si existe y false si no, luego es meter la llamada a la función en un if para saber si haces la inserción o mandas un mensaje de error.

```
if(!existeUsuario(et1.getText().toString())){
    registrologin(null);
}
else { 
    //mostrar error de usuario existente
}
```

Comment: Hola, antetodo muchas gracias por contestar, lo que quiero es que la tabla tenga solo 1 registro, es decir, y si voy a introducir otro, no me deje, no quiero que me diga que ese registro ya existe, si no, que al haber ya uno, no me deje registrar otro

Comment: En ese caso simplemente tendrías que eliminar la condición WHERE y devolver c.getCount() en lugar de moveToFirst(). Eso te debería dar el numero de registros encontrados por la consulta que al no tener filtro si ya existe un usuario te devolverá un 1 y entonces no haces la inserción.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que yo en tiendo, lo que quieres hacer es que en tabla X solo quieres que tenga únicamente un solo registro...

Si es así, una opción que puedes hacer es hacer un SELECT COUNT(*) y si da mas de 0 no dejar hacer el insert...

Si a lo que te refieres es a hacer que cada usuario sea único en la BBDD, como ya te han dicho, realiza una búsqueda previa por el usuario, si lo encuentras, no dejes hacer el insert.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Victor, gracias por contestar,  correcto, lo que quiero es que la tabla x solo tenta, un registro, podrias decirme como seria el SELECT COUNT en mi caso?, estoy muy perdido muchisimas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer algo parecido a esto (lo he hecho en notepad que ahora mismo no tengo acceso al IDE): 

`public int comprobar(){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"registro.db", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM registro;");
        return c.getCount();
    }`

El metodo devuelve 0 si no hay nada en la tabla o 1 si ya hay un registro.

Comment: gracias nuevamente por contestar, pero no logro hacerlo, te agredecia mucho si pudueras mostrarme donde iria el codigo dentro del mio, si puedes claro esa, mucha gracias

Comment: ya lo tengo!!! muchas gracias por todo!!